# Logo does not display after uploading it

Tags: media

After I selected the logo in the theme settings (Appearance > Settings > Choose File), I clicked 'Save Configuration'. It says 'custom logo path is invalid'. I did not have write permission for the default folder under sites. After i gave write permission to the default directory, I did not get the above error.

Now, I am able to upload the logo  but I am not able to see the uploaded logo on my page. Do you know why my logo does not display on my page after I uploading it successfully?

Comment: There are many potential reasons for this. Right click your logo "broken image" placeholder, and select "Copy image URL". Paste it in a new tab and see if you see the logo. If not, 1) Check that your path is correct, 2) Check that your logo exists in the path 3) Check your folder permissions

Comment: I changed the folder(default under sites) permission to 777. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! But please, try at least 755, since 777 is granting all permissions to all users and that is not ideal.